# Sharepoint 2013 .Net CSOM search across "All Sites"

Tags: 2013, search, client-object-model

I'm creating a new ClientContext:

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(targetUrl);
```

When trying to do a simple search:

```
KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(clientContext);
keywordQuery.QueryText = "test";
SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor(clientContext);
var results = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

The results are returned, but only for the site from the `targetUrl` used in the context.  Is there any way to return results across all sites using .Net CSOM Search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to add `<AppPermissionRequest Scope=”http://sharepoint/search” Right=”QueryAsUserIgnoreAppPrincipal” />` to appmanifest.xml to query against the farm.  Without setting this permissions, search will only return results from the site the app is installed on.

Answer (score 0):

You could tweak the query text by introducing **ContentClass** managed property, to retrieve results across all the sites:

```
keywordQuery.QueryText = "contentclass=\"STS_Web\" AND contentclass=\"STS_Site\"";
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but, I might have misspoke.  I'm not trying to get all sites, I'm trying to search across all sites

Comment: Sorry, I meant to search across all sites but I missed out on some words. See my updated response. The query will you results across all sites.